# fill a input from asp:label

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

A value will be typed into a asp:textbox, then when you hit submit it will generate a asp:label, What i need is to get the generated asp:label and have it passed to an HTML input field. I would like this either in HTML or JavaScript format.

```
<asp:TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" ID="usrpart" runat="server" Width="75px"  style='text-transform:uppercase' CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox><!--entered text and click submit-->

<asp:Label id="usrpart0" runat="server"></asp:label><br /><!--displays what was typed in the textbox and submitted to the server-->

<input id="asptext" type="hidden" value=""> <!--this is where i need asp:label's value passed--><!--this value is used to generate a QR code>
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get **label** value

```
var name = document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>").value;
```

Assigning the value to the **textbox**:

```
 document.getElementById("asptext").value = name ;
```

I made a **demo** based on your requirement here is the working demo

**HTML**

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="javascript:return CallService();" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

            <asp:TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" ID="usrpart" runat="server" Width="75px"  style='text-transform:uppercase' CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox><!--entered text and click submit-->

<asp:Label id="usrpart0" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />

<input id="asptext" type="hidden" value=""/> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Javscript**

```
function CallService() {
            var usrpart0 = document.getElementById("<%=usrpart.ClientID %>").value;
            document.getElementById("<%=usrpart0.ClientID %>").innerHTML = usrpart0;
            document.getElementById("asptext").value = document.getElementById("<%=usrpart0.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
            alert(document.getElementById("asptext").value);
        }
```